# How to pass parametrized interface into class in Kotlin?

Tags: android, class, kotlin, interface

I have parametrized interface like this: 
`interface myInterface<T>: A<T>, B<T>, C<T>`
and I want to put this interface in class as parameter, like this:
`class myClass(private val interface: myInterface<T>){}`. 
How to do it in Kotlin?

Answer (score 1):

You have two mistakes:

– You cannot use a keyword like 'interface' as name of a variable (you could by using back-ticks like this `interface`, but I would not recommend that).

– You need to parametrise your class with <T>.

```
interface A<T>
interface B<T>
interface C<T>

interface MyInterface<T>: A<T>, B<T>, C<T>

class MyClass<T>(
  private val `interface`: MyInterface<T>
) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, I understand, that was example, my interfaces and vars names are different :) Previous answer was useful! I have to implement parametrized interfaces, so I Can't do it like this.